# Access denied when closing folder using SHDocVw

Tags: c#, process, shdocvw

I try to close a folder by its path using `SHDocVw`. It's not working:

> Acces deined.

I run my program as an administrator.

```
ShellWindows _shellWindows = new SHDocVw.ShellWindows();
string processType;
foreach (InternetExplorer ie in _shellWindows)
{
    processType = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(ie.FullName).ToLower();
    if (processType.Equals("explorer") && ie.LocationURL.Contains(mypath))
    {
        ie.Quit();
    }
}
```

Comment: Where is  LocationUrl pointing to? The window is started by the same user that runs this code?

Comment: "mypath" is LocationUrl. The same user run this code.

Comment: yes, what is the value of mypath.